# Retrieve object from a list Rcpp

Tags: r, list, rcpp

I'm new to Rcpp and I'm struggling with it. I have a function that return a list with 2 objects: max and argmax from a vector. I would like to retrieve only max or only argmax from that list in another function. How can I do that?
Below an example:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List max_argmax_cpp(NumericVector x){
  double max = x[0];
  int argmax = 0 + 1;
  for(int i = 1; i < x.length(); i++){
    if(x[i]>x[i-1]){
      max = x[i];
      argmax = i+1;
    }
  }
  List Output;
  Output["Max"] = max;  
  Output["Argmax"] = argmax;
  return(Output);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int max_only(NumericVector x){
  int max = **only max from max_argmax_cpp(x)**;
  return(max);
}
```

Comment: When you use Rcpp Attributes, the C++ function names are rewritten for you as the goal is an _R function_ of the name of your C++ function.  So here I would recommend splitting `max_argmax_cpp()` into two functions: one that does the work, and what that is callable from R. Your new function `max_only()` can then call the worker function and return just one argument.

Comment: This is an example, but the real situation is that I have an MCMC and I generate a list with 3 variables, that I need to use in another function. If I split into 3 separate functions I have two problems: (1) it will take 3x more time, (2) I will retrieve data from 2 separate MCMC chains, and this will lead me to wrong results. Is there a way to choose pick only an object from another functions list? (obs: each object from this list is a matrix)

Comment: I think you misunderstand what I wrote. One function that does the work.  Two interfaces, ie two accessor functions that call the worker function.  If you want to microoptimise and not assign `argmax` then you can signal that with another option.

Comment: As for the "more work" vs "not identical streams" I think you may have design question for yourself.  That does not strike me as an Rcpp question.  Or maybe I just misunderstand what you are after...

Comment: Can you give me an example on the "Two interfaces"?  My question is on how to return multiple objects from one function, at the same time. I was using a List variable to do the job, but I don't know how to access it inside another function.

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppexamples/blob/master/src/ListExample.cpp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second example you can simply call your original function and assign it to a `List`, whose elements can the be retrieved by name (or position):

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List max_argmax_cpp(NumericVector x){
  double max = x[0];
  int argmax = 0 + 1;
  for(int i = 1; i < x.length(); i++){
    if(x[i]>x[i-1]){
      max = x[i];
      argmax = i+1;
    }
  }
  List Output;
  Output["Max"] = max;  
  Output["Argmax"] = argmax;
  return(Output);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double max_only(NumericVector x){
  List l = max_argmax_cpp(x);
  double max = l["Max"];
  return(max);
} 
/*** R
set.seed(42)
x <- runif(100)
max_argmax_cpp(x)
max_only(x)
*/
```

Output:

```
> set.seed(42)

> x <- runif(100)

> max_argmax_cpp(x)
$Max
[1] 0.7439746

$Argmax
[1] 99


> max_only(x)
[1] 0.7439746
```

Comment: I confused myself between this case -- and the C++ function is of course visible in the same compilation unit -- with a more complicated case of calling from R that used to not work via `inline`.  Thanks for setting this straight.